# How to save and download file with Rest assured like the way postman provide save and download

Tags: java, rest-assured

I am using rest assured to get the response from api whose response contains .xls file . Like Postman (which provides save and download option and saves the response as file) does rest assured provides such way

Comment: Try this - https://github.com/eviltester/libraryexamples/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/compendiumdev/libraryexamples/restassured/DownloadAFileExampleTest.java

Answer (score 4):

Use

`.get(...).asInputStream()`

or

`.extract().asInputStream()`

See [examples](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/blob/master/examples/rest-assured-itest-java/src/test/java/io/restassured/itest/java/FileDownloadITest.java).